# Levenshtein Generalization for Graphs?

Tags: graph, fuzzy, levenshtein-distance

Is there a generalization of the levenshtein distance for searching for structures in graphs?

Comment: These are helpful links.  I'm not sure what I meant specifically.  Just looking for some leads to refine my understanding of graph search and comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This paper might be of interest: [Structural Similarity in Graphs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.73.5731&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I am however afraid that calculating such distance would be very computationally intensive, most likely either NP or NP complete.